# Django Reportlab PDF

Tags: django

Использую Reportlab в проекте Django. Пока что только как формирование строки.

- как я могу формировать таблицы, добавлять изображения? (есть ли
  какая-либо инструкция на русском языке с примерами?)
- завожу строки так: `p.drawString(200, 500, value)` т.е. используются координаты. Допустим у меня есть сплошной текст и в него
  мне нужно вставить мою переменную(например имя пользователя) и
  следовательно нужно добавлять кучу строк `p.drawString` с выверенными
  координатами? или есть разумный способ?
- можно ли с помощью Reportlab формировать CSV и Word документы? если нет, то что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот фрагмент формирования довольно большого PDF, надеюсь поможет уловить направление, тут и таблицы и кастомные шрифты и вставка изображений, номеров страниц, далее еще формируются разнообразные графики в зависимости от пришедших параметров:

```
def conclusion_to_pdf(s_id):
tests = SeanceTests.objects.filter(seance=s_id)
seances = Seance.objects.select_related().get(id=s_id)

filename = seances.profile.account.username + '_results.pdf'
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="%s"' % filename

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Times', 'times.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Times-Bold', 'timesbd.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Times-Italic', 'timesi.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Times-BoldItalic', 'timesbi.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
from reportlab.lib.fonts import addMapping
addMapping('Times', 0, 0, 'Times')    #normal
addMapping('Times', 0, 1, 'Times-Italic')    #italic
addMapping('Times', 1, 0, 'Times-Bold')    #bold
addMapping('Times', 1, 1, 'Times-BoldItalic')    #italic and bold
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, pagesize=A4, rightMargin=40, leftMargin=40, topMargin=20, bottomMargin=40, title='Результаты')
story = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY, fontName='Times', fontSize=11))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify-Bold', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY, fontName='Times-Bold'))
bold_style = styles['Justify-Bold']
normal_style = styles['Justify']
doc_title = copy.copy(styles["Heading1"])
doc_title.alignment = TA_CENTER
doc_title.fontName = 'Times-Bold'
doc_title.fontSize = 16
title = 'Отчет по результатам тестирования'
story.append(Paragraph(title, doc_title))
# logo
from psycho2.settings import STATIC_PATH
logo = STATIC_PATH + '/img/logo.png'
im = Image(logo, 70*mm, 30*mm)
story.append(im)
story.append(Spacer(1, 10))

result_table_style = TableStyle([
    ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Times-Bold', 10),
    ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (15, -2), colors.lightgrey),
])

normal_table_style = TableStyle([
        ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Times', 10),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), 'CENTRE'),
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE')
    ])

# for u in context['seances']:
personal_data = [
    [u'ФИО', "%s %s %s" % (seances.profile.account.last_name, seances.profile.account.first_name, seances.profile.account.middle_name)],
    [u'Год рождения', seances.profile.year],
    [u'Пол', seances.profile.get_sex_display()],
    [u'Семейное положение', seances.profile.get_marital_status_display()],
    [u'Образование', seances.profile.get_education_display()],
    [u'Профессия', seances.profile.professional_sphere],
    [u'Дата завершения сеанса', seances.finished_date]
]
table = Table(personal_data, rowHeights=15)
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Times', 10),
    ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), 'RIGHT'),
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
]))
story.append(table)
story.append(Spacer(1, 10))
doc_title.fontSize = 12
```

... 
далее много всего
... 
ну и в финале:

```
doc.build(story, canvasmaker=PageNumCanvas)
return response
```

response используйте на свое усмотрение, либо отображение в броузере, либо сохранить в файл и прицепить к письму. 
Насчет CSV есть отдельные утилиты в python для формирования с CSV. Для Word так же есть отдельные пакеты. 
Что еще можно делать с ReportLab - формировать графики (очень разнообразные) в виде изображений. Если будете использовать, то рекомендую сохранять в формате svg иначе если есть русские шрифты в графике, будет много танцев с бубном.